# python: removing 1st word in string using partition(" ")

Tags: python

i am using the following to try remove the first character from the string

```
details[2].partition(" ")[2]
```

but it does not do anything

below is the current string (list)(before and after)

> ['n/a', '(5yo+) ', '2m½f Good 9 hdles', '2m90y)']

and the desired output would be

> ['n/a', '(5yo+) ', 'Good 9 hdles', '2m90y)']

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How exactly are you modifying the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never assign the result to the original list.  Try this.

```
details[2] = details[2].partition(' ')[2]
```

Comment: Brilliant ... i thought it was something simple. Thank you (new to python)

Comment: @emmaperkins Pls mark as the answer if this helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question well. This would do the trick as per my understanding.

```
details = ['n/a', '(5yo+) ', '2m½f Good 9 hdles', '2m90y)']

print (details[2].split(' ', 1)[1] )
```